# Xpath function selecting cell with matching text from another cell

Tags: xpath

I am trying to determine xpath of cell from search results matching the text from search parameter text in previous table. 
In this example it shows that the case number searched is: 14-CV-12-14. 
Then it lists 3 variable options: 14-CV-00-1214, 14-CV-01-214, and 14-CV-12-14. 
Of course I only want the one that matches the number searched, but it isn't always in the last row, so I'm unable to use a last() function.

```
<table>
 removed previous code
</table>
```

How do I select the cell containing text that matches the text of a cell in a different table? Thank you in advance for any help with this!

OK, let me be more specific with the code I'm working with.

- The 1st table indicates which number was searched (14-CV-12-14).
- The 2nd table lists three options of similar numbers, one of them matches the number from the 1st table.
- I need the xpath that always returns the number in 2nd table that matches the number from 1st table.

Actual HTML (edited):

```
<table 1>
 <tr></tr>
 <tr>
    <td id="SearchParamList" colspan="2">
        <b>
            Search By:
        </b>
         Case   
        <b>
            Exact Name:
        </b>
         on   
        <b>
            Case Search Mode:
        </b>
         Number   
        <b>
            Case Number:
        </b>
         14-CV-12-11   
        <b>
            All
        </b>
         All   
        <b>
            Sort By:
        </b>
         Filed Date   
    </td>
 </tr>
</table 1>

<table 2>
    <tr>
        <th class="ssSearchResultHeader" nowrap="true">
            <b>
                Case Number
            </b>
        </th>
        <th class="ssSearchResultHeader" nowrap="true">
            <b>
                Style
            </b>
        </th>
        <th class="ssSearchResultHeader">
            <b>
                Filed/Location/Judicial Officer
            </b>
        </th>
        <th class="ssSearchResultHeader" nowrap="true">
            <b>
                Type
            </b>
            <b>
                /Status
            </b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <a style="color: blue" href="CaseDetail.aspx?CaseID=581">
                14-CV-00-1214
            </a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            RENT A CENTER PLAINTIFF VS CYNTHIA MCPHERSON DEFEN…
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <div>
                01/27/2000
            </div>
            <div>
                - Hennepin Civil
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <div>
                Transcript Judgment
            </div>
            <div>
                Closed
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <a style="color: blue" href="CaseDetail.aspx?CaseID=669">
                14-CV-01-214
            </a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            FRANCHISE WHOLESALE CO., LLC, A MISSOURI LIMITED L…
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <div>
                01/05/2001
            </div>
            <div>
                - Hennepin Civil
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <div>
                Default Judgment
            </div>
            <div>
                Closed
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <a style="color: blue" href="CaseDetail.aspx?CaseID=167">
                14-CV-12-11
            </a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
             Capital One Bank USA NA vs Jill A Hildebrant
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <div>
                12/30/2011
            </div>
            <div>
                - Hennepin Civil
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="true">
            <div>
                Default Judgment
            </div>
            <div>
                Closed
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table 2>
```

Is this clear?

Comment: the smart quotes and linebreaks are exactly like this in your source document?

Comment: Yes. It's from the page I'm retrieving the data from. I'm not the designer.

Comment: Double check that it's not straight quotes?

Comment: The quotes were visible when inspecting elements in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I editing the code in the questions from a direct cut/paste from the site.

Comment: Always cut and paste from the source code, never from the developer tools. Your modified code sample is still syntactically invalid (`<table 1>` is not possible in HTML).

Comment: I understand, but with delicate XPath it's necessary that the source code is all-right.

Comment: Yes, I should have left the <table> tags simple. I felt the need to modify the original code as it was very extensive with extraneous code that might make it difficult to sort through in order to understand my question. 

But I understand where you are coming from. It makes it easier for someone helping to cut/paste into another editor to work on. I recognize that everyone answering questions and providing contributions are doing so on their own time, sharing their knowledge for free. I am very grateful for  the guidance from you and everyone here!

Comment: You notice that you can edit your comments, don't you? :)